# How to create a vendor record from a customer record? and attach it to "other relationship" field by SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

i am creating a customer record in an userevent aftersubmit script. After that i need to create and attach a vendor record with same name, in the `other relationship` field in the relationships tab on the customer record.
[image]
Can anyone guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a suite answers topic 74233 on this.

In short:

```js
    recid = 5; //current Lead Id
    // Get Domain from URL Module . URL Module supports absolute path, compared to SS 1.0 where the relative path was used
    var domain = 'https://';
    domain += url.resolveDomain({hostType:url.HostType.APPLICATION, accountId:runtime.accountId});
    var sample_url = '/app/common/entity/company.nl?e=T&target=s_relation:otherrelationships&
    label=Other+Relationships&fromtype=custjob&id=' + recid + '&totype=vendor';
    var response = https.request({method: https.Method.GET ,url: sample_url });
```